# Jquery :not() selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code which allows to remove text from child nodes like this:

```
$.fn.removeText = function() {
    for (var i=this.length-1; i>=0; --i) removeText(this[i]);
};
function removeText(node) {
    if (!node) return;
    for (var i=node.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
        var childNode = node.childNodes[i];
        if (childNode.nodeType === 3) node.removeChild(childNode);
        else if (childNode.nodeType === 1) removeText(childNode);
    }   
} 
$('body').removeText();
```

So now I'm trying to exclude elements, for instance the span like this:

```
$('body:not(span)').removeText();
```

It's not working, everything is getting removed. I tried several other (Jquery) things with no luck. Do I have to alter the `removeText()` function? I really would like to stick to Jquery..Is there something else I can try?

[Example JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcKsX/2/)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to filter out with that selector? *No* `body` is a `span`, so it *can't* match anything as written.

Comment: @David Thomas I don't understand..Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Your selector, as written, selects the `body` tag and then uses the string supplied to the `:not()` selector to remove elements from the selection. Because the `body` is not a `span` no elements will be removed. Read the [`:not()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

Comment: @qwerty Those are the 'other things' I tried which didn't work

Comment: @David Thomas I understand now, thanks for pointing that out, but even if I write it the right way as the answers below it still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a space between `body` and the `:not()` selector

```
$("body :not(span)")
```

Without the space, what you practically say is give me the body, that is not a span element - which always will be true and return just the body-element.

With the space, you say, give me all children to the body-element that are not span elements.

**Update:**

I believe the problem you see is that jQuery doesn't select text-nodes (at least as far as I know). This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4399718/678801) suggest a way to select descendant text-nodes.

In your fiddle, the only descendant element to the body that would be selectable is the span, and you opt-out from that element with your `:not(span)` selector.

Comment: @Christofer Eliasson That shouldn't matter, the Jquery part is about excluding some element _before_ the function is done

Comment: @Christofer Eliasson I tried the code (with :not) on bbc news website, which consist out of a lot more than spans, it didn't work

Comment: @Youss Then I'm not sure I understand what the problem is, or what you want your code to do. In [this simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/hcKsX/5/), I've changed the selector and added a div that will match it, and the text of the div is removed just fine. Isn't that what you are after, or am I completely missing something here?

Comment: You are right, thanks:) To bad it's so complicated to remove all the text

Comment: @Youss: It's not complicated at all.

Comment: If you still want to have some fun...go to this website [nu.nl](http://www.nu.nl) And add (with console) the Jquery library in the head `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` Then add the code and click enter, you will see my problem...it doesn't work on a bigger scale it seems.

Comment: Check my answer for final conclusion on this:)

Answer (score 1):

That selector `$('body:not(span)')` means you want all the `body` tags which are not span.

Try `$(':not(span)')` instead.

Comment: Does he even need to specify `body`? Can't he just do `$(':not(span)')`? Because everything will be inside `body` anyways.

Comment: @qwerty True! But in his fiddle, I think he want to reach the text which isn't wrapped by any other tag than `body`. So my selector doesn't work for him

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

`$("body").find("*").not('span').removeText();`

Comment: another way is $('body').find(':not(span)').length;

Answer (score 0):

easiest would be adding a wrapper around everything.

`<div class="wrapper">`

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/gPB6e/

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple way of doing this in case anyone is interested. It was right there in the Jquery docs, and sooooooo easy...

```
    $('body *').contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType == 3;
    })

//Then do your thing
      .remove();
```

[JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gPB6e/3/)

Comment: I can't believe all the anwsers I found Googling for two days now are so over complex...